# Prove $\sum x_n < \infty \implies \sum \frac{\sqrt {x_n}}{n} < \infty$ if $x_n \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given $ \sum x_n  < \infty$ , I need to show that this implies $\sum \frac{\sqrt {x_n}}{n} < \infty $ if $x_n \geq 0$

I thought of using **Abel's test** to test the convergence but that test couldn't be applied here as $ \sum x_n  < \infty \nRightarrow  \sum \sqrt{x_n}  < \infty$  . I am completely stuck at this point. Any hint how to approach?

Comment: $$
0 \leq \left(\,\sqrt{x_{n}} - {1 \over 2n}\,\right)^{2} = x_{n} - {\sqrt{x_{n}} \over n} + {1 \over 4n^{2}}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
{\sqrt{x_{n}} \over n} \leq x_{n} + {1 \over 4n^{2}}
$$

Comment: Not sure why the reopen vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint :

Compare your expression with : $$\sum \frac{1}{n^2} + \sum x_{n}$$

Hint 2: 
Cauchy inequality

Comment: I would  compare (the square of the original sum) with the product of the above two, rather than their sum.